# Webpack build success but npm webpack build no output

Tags: node.js, webpack, bundling-and-minification

In command prompt, if I type webpack and press enter, the output entry.min.js can be generated correctly.  However, if I type npm build and press enter, nothing generated.

Is there anything wrong with my package.json or webpack.config.js?

BTW, is there a way to generate a bundled & minified CSS instead of a JS file?
Because the input is a CSS file but it gives me a JS file.

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "assets",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Front End Assets",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "Mozilla Public License Version 2.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
}
```

**WebPack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        entry:"./src/entry.js"
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/bundle",
        filename: "[name].min.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" }
        ]
    }
};
```

**Entry.js**

```
require ("./common/reset.css");
```

**Reset.css**

```
html {
  font-family: sans-serif; /* 1 */
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Remove default margin (opinionated).
 */
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to run

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
}
```

You should type in command line:

```
npm run build
```

---

#### Splitting css and js

Your configuration in `webpack.config.js` will create single `.js` file with styles inside - this is normal behaviour.

If you want to extract css from js you should take a look at this plugin [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin).